# linux app dynamic libs

Tags: c++, arm

I have a Linux application which is linked with a dynamic library, the library is only linked (no functions is called from the app). For some reason app doesn't start and I don't know why, it seems to be stuck. I've made a 2nd dynamic library, a very simple one, to test if there is any problem with my settings or my Linux app has some issues.
Unfortunately (or not?) this time my app has started, also I could call a function from this simple dynamic library. I've compared dependencies between both dynamic libraries, both of them seems to use same libs dependencies, I've compiled&linked with same options (I will check again this) ....

Do you have any idea when\why an application linked with a library could stiff even I don't call a function from that lib?

The application is for an embedded system, ARM A9 Linux based, the debug isn't easy\clear at moment, I have to ask for it.

Comment: is it maybe a 32bit lib in an 64bit app? On linux you can use the program readelf to check that. Or is the library in an unknown path?

Comment: I didn't use any switch for32\64, both libs use the same syntax  (or almost, I have to check it again) for compiling and linking, both libs are in the same path

Comment: how did u check the dependencies of both libraries, the working and not-working one?

Comment: objdump -p /path_to_lib | grep NEEDED

Comment: I've found a way to have console over COM, my app is killed because "Segmentation fault occurred at 00000004"....this is happening when i link first lib